# Where does Drupal set the uploaded file name syntax?

Tags: files

I have a file with a filename which has a double underscore in it. When Drupal saves the file, it shortens it to be only one. ie:

> Snapshot__john_doe_2_opt.jpg

When Drupal saves the file, it removes one of the underscores and names it this:

> Snapshot_john_doe_2_opt.jpg

Where does Drupal do this? I need to account for any changes which Drupal makes to the filename and I need to know what other characters it may remove etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [transliteration](https://www.drupal.org/project/transliteration) module.

and in code use code like

```
function hook_transliteration_clean_filename_prepare_alter(&$filename, $source_langcode) {
  $filename = drupal_strtolower($filename);
  $filename = str_replace('__','_', $filename);
}
```

Above code is not tested, Hope it will help you.